# Freezing last 2 rows in a kendo grid

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid

Is it possible to "freeze the last 5 rows" (always show up when scrolling) of data in a Kendo grid? I tried to search this one in Google, but I can't fine any solutions.

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean "freeze the last 5 rows"? always appear when paging or always show up when scrolling?

Comment: always show up when scrolling...

Answer (score 0):

No, this isn't possible. You can however use two Kendo UI grids - the first is scrollable and the second shows the last five rows.